# How to resubmit a webform that's in Drupal but not in Civi

Tags: webform-civicrm

A webform was submitted & made it to Drupal but not to Civi.  It's a fairly simple 'new contact' submission with 4 screens so quite a lot of information - and I can see the webform result.  It has 'Contact 1' blank which is a sign of some problem but all the required fields are completed.  Is there a way of actually resubmitting it so it gets to Civi?  I've gone into 'Edit' and stepped through the 4 screens but that just saves it - I want to actually resubmit it. This is a Drupal 7 install with Civi at 5.42.1

Comment: Andy, yes if you click 'edit' on the submission and add the data for Contact 1 then save it should repush that data to civi.

Comment: I tried that and it just results in the webform being saved & doesn't push it to Civi. It has the first,  last name and email of of 'Contact 1' although in the 'Results' tab the 'Contact 1' column is blank.  Other submissions for the same webform were fine, so a puzzle

Comment: odd. have def. worked for us but perhaps never had to try it for the contact themselves

Comment: We have some very similar type webforms that report to Civi and on occasion, the submission doesn't make it there. To date, I've always been able to edit the submission and resave - all the contacts etc are created in civi as expected. I know that's not happening for you. Just seconding that in theory it works.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there are two issues: 1) resubmit the form & 2) have that submit hit civi.

First issue: go to the form -> then click on settings -> then check the appropriate options under form and submission tabs. You may be interested in the below one under the submission tab:

```
Allow users to duplicate previous submissions
```

Second issue: it depends on whether the form is setup to communicate with civi. That is done via clicking the form then  ->settings -> civicrm tab and checking

```
Enable CiviCRM Processing
```

If that is done and there are glitches, then look into the Drupal reports -> recent log messages (but first test submit the form).

- Haven't looked at Drupal 7. If the above resubmit isn't available in D7,  maybe do it via programmatically, see this and other snippets.  https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2911356

With hooks and such you can probably update the submission and resumbit it both to Drupal and civi.

Comment: I think the ability to duplicate a previous submisssion is only available in Drupal 8, unfortunately, As I said, this is a Drupal 7 install.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: On my D7 sites, I've just had to have two windows open and copy the data from the webform submission to a new webform submission.